# Returning a result after nesting for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, break

I'm trying to figure out how to get the below code to push the biggestNumber variable to the largestNumbers variable so that the largest number in each sub-array of largestOfFour will be returned as an array of largestNumbers.

I see it mentally and thought that I was writing the code correctly. This is my thought process:

1) largestNumbers is set up as an empty array.

2) create a for loop that will pull each sub-array during a loop and store it as PulledSubArray.

3) I need to loop through the sub-array(pulled
SubArray) with a for loop.

4) biggestNumber variable is set-up to store the biggest number in the sub-array and an if statement is set-up to determine which number is the biggest and then push that number to the largestNumbers array.

5) break the inner for loop and then repeat steps for second sub-array.

Without giving the answer to the entire challenge, could you tell me what syntax or elements I'm missing to achieve my end result

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

  var largestNumbers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i > arr.length; i++){

   var pulledSubArray = arr[i];

    for (var n = 0; n > pulledSubArray.length; n++){

      var biggestNumber = 0;

      if (pulledSubArray[n] > biggestNumber){

        biggestNumber = pulledSubArray[n];

      } else if (pulledSubArray[n] < biggestNumber){

        largestNumbers.push(biggestNumber);
        break;

      }         
    }           
  }                              

 return largestNumbers;

}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: what is the issue that youre having?

Comment: Do you want to get largest number from each nested array?

Comment: Your `for` loop conditions are wrong. Have another look at them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get largest number in each sub array:

```js
var data = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

function largestOfFour(data) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, d)
  })  
}

console.log(largestOfFour(data))
```

Or even shorter (es6):

```js
let data = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

const largestOfFour = data => data.map(d => Math.max.apply(null, d))

console.log(largestOfFour(data))
```

Comment: Your es6 example could do with a lot less `()`

Comment: `(data)` can be `data` The `()` are optional if you only have 1 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i > arr.length; i++){
                  ^
             Wrong condition
```

Your loop constructs are wrong. Correct them. A simple version of your function looks like (ECMAScript6)

```
const largestOfFour = (arr) => arr.map(el => Math.max(...el));
```

In case you want to stick to your thought

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var largestNumbers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {    // Correct loop condition
    var pulledSubArray = arr[i];
    var biggestNumber = pulledSubArray[0];
    for (var n = 1; n < pulledSubArray.length; n++) {    // Correct loop condition
      if (pulledSubArray[n] > biggestNumber) {
        biggestNumber = pulledSubArray[n];
      }
    }
    largestNumbers.push(biggestNumber);    // Push biggest number outside the inner loop
  }
  return largestNumbers;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with Code:

1. **Logic**:

```js
if (pulledSubArray[n] > biggestNumber) {
  biggestNumber = pulledSubArray[n];
} else if (pulledSubArray[n] < biggestNumber) {
  largestNumbers.push(biggestNumber);
  break;
}
```

For an array `[4, 5, 1, 3]`, for second iteration, `biggestNumber` holds `4` and `pulledSubArray[n]` will hold `5`. For this case, is you would push the value and break the loop. But you are not checking the entire array. So you will not get accurate result.

2. **Loop condition**:

```js
for (var i = 0; i > arr.length; i++){
```

This will never enter the loop. It should be `i < arr.length`

3. **Variable declaration**:

```js
for (var n = 0; n > pulledSubArray.length; n++) {
  var biggestNumber = 0;
  if (pulledSubArray[n] > biggestNumber) {
```

Variable should be declared outside the loop. You are currently setting its value to `0` in every iteration. So you will eventually get the last value as `if (pulledSubArray[n] > biggestNumber)` will always return true.

---

**Updated Code:**

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var largestNumbers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var pulledSubArray = arr[i];
    var biggestNumber = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < pulledSubArray.length; n++) {
      if (pulledSubArray[n] > biggestNumber) {
        biggestNumber = pulledSubArray[n];
      }
    }
    largestNumbers.push(biggestNumber)
  }
  return largestNumbers;
}

var list = largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);

console.log(list)
```